# Distinct Row Values as Column with group by on another field

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I've loans data and I want to group by month of date and get amount via distinct product

My data looks like this

```
disbursementdate | amount | product | cluster
2017-01-01       | 1000   | HL      | West
2018-02-01       | 1000   | PL      | East
```

So After querying, I'd ideally want the result to look like this

```
   Month            | HL   | PL
   January 2018     | 1000 | 0
   February 2018    | 100  | 1000
```

Please note that there could be more products and there's no way of knowing how many unique ... so `sum case when` wouldnt work

I'm struggling with query

Comment: How did you get February 2018 HL = 100 ?

Comment: @jpp ... just used dummy values

Comment: It's a good idea to supply desired output *consistent* with your input. Otherwise, you will confuse both people trying to help you *and* future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas and the purpose-built method [`pd.DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
import pandas as pd

# read data
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

# extract month
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['disbursementdate']).apply(lambda x: x.replace(day=1))

# pivot results
res = df.pivot_table(index='Month', columns='product', values='amount',
                     aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0).reset_index()

# reformat month
res['Month'] = res['Month'].dt.strftime('%B %Y')

print(res)

product          Month    HL    PL
0         January 2017  1000     0
1        February 2018     0  1000
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in mysql by building code to execute for example

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T(disbursementdate DATE, amount INT, product VARCHAR(2), cluster VARCHAR(4));
INSERT INTO T VALUES
('2017-01-01'       , 1000   , 'HL'    ,   'West'),
('2017-01-01'       , 1000   , 'OL'    ,   'West'),
('2018-02-01'       , 1000   , 'PL'    ,   'East'),
('2018-02-01'       , 100    , 'HL'    ,   'West'),
('2018-02-01'       , 1000   , 'HL'    ,   'West');


SET @SQL = 

(SELECT CONCAT('SELECT DISBURSEMENTDATE,',
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN PRODUCT = ', CHAR(39),S.PRODUCT, CHAR(39),' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS ',S.PRODUCT))
,' FROM T GROUP BY DISBURSEMENTDATE;')
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT PRODUCT FROM T) S
)
;

PREPARE SQLSTMT FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE SQLSTMT;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE SQLSTMT;

+------------------+------+------+------+
| DISBURSEMENTDATE | HL   | OL   | PL   |
+------------------+------+------+------+
| 2017-01-01       | 1000 | 1000 |    0 |
| 2018-02-01       | 1100 |    0 | 1000 |
+------------------+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```